# standard deviation arraylist error

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, standard-deviation

I am getting an error when I try to retrieve the individual values to find the variance in the process of calculating the standard deviation. I can't figure out whether to use .get() or .getValue and I am lost. I have already calculated the average.

```
final ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder>>(uaCount.entrySet());


for(Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder> entry : entries)  //iterating over the sorted hashmap
{

    double temp = 0;
    double variance = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= entry.getValue().occurrences ; i ++)
        {               
            temp += ((entry.getValue(i).singleValues) - average)*((entry.getValue(i).singleValues) - average);

            variance = temp/entry.getValue().occurrences;
        }

        double stdDev = Math.sqrt(variance);
```

This is my NumberHolder class, which I populate in my main funcion. I am using this equation for standard deviation: http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html

based on my code, occurrences is N and the values from the singleValues arraylist are Xi

```
public static class NumberHolder
{
    public int occurrences = 0;
    public int sumtime_in_milliseconds = 0; 
    public ArrayList<Long> singleValues = new ArrayList<Long>();
}
```

This is the error I get. :

```
The method getValue() in the type Map.Entry<String,series3.NumberHolder> is not applicable for the arguments (int).
```

If you need to see more code please just ask, I didn't want to put anything unnecessary but I might have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take `int` as argument in [`Map.Entry#getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29). So in your code it should be `entry.getValue()` *instead of* `entry.getValue(i)`. Now apart from this your `singleValues` is an `ArrayList` . so you can't subtract it from integer `average` in line `(entry.getValue(i).singleValues) - average)`. You have to first extract out the element from the `ArrayList` and then subtract it from the `average`. Your for loop should be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().occurrences ; i ++)// i < entry.getValue() to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException
{               
   temp += ((entry.getValue().singleValues.get(i)) - average)*((entry.getValue().singleValues.get(i)) - average);
   variance = temp/entry.getValue().occurrences;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how the < rather than the <= avoids the exception?

Comment: @user2007843 Because I guess that occurrences is the size of your ArrayList (say 6). If you use `i <=..` then in last iteration `i` will have value `6`. But `ArrayList` is `indexed based` dynamic resizable `array` which starts from `0` and ends with `size()-1` which is `5`. So when you try to get element at `6th` index of `ArrayList` it will throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 2):

Error means exactly what it says.  You can't pass an int argument to `getValue()`.

Change `entry.getValue(i)` to `entry.getValue()` and it should work fine.

I assume it is something like `entry.getValue().singleValues.get(i)` that you want.  If `occurrences` is always equal to `entry.getValue().singleValues.size()` consider getting rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

[getValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) doesn't take an integer argument. You can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().singleValues.size(); i++) {
   Long singleValue = entry.getValue().singleValues.get(i);
   temp += (singleValue - average) * (singleValue - average);

   variance = temp / entry.getValue().occurrences;
}
```

Also `ArrayLists` are zero based so you should end on `size - 1`.

Comment: sorry I should have put this in the OP, but this is the error when I tried that `The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) ArrayList<Long>`

Comment: You will need to extract a numeric value from the `singleValues` `ArrayList` to do a calculation though

Comment: Might want to change `.singleValues(i)` to `.singleValues.get(i)`.

Comment: okay yea now I have this but I just got a IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1, Size 1 `temp += (entry.getValue().singleValues.get(i) - average) * ((entry.getValue().singleValues.get(i)) - average);`